# iOS app transition by custom url scheme takes too much time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am testing inter app communication like this.
App A -(1)-> App B -(2)-> App A

The transition (1) takes more than 10 seconds. (2) is fast. App B is almost empty app, handling URL from App A and openURL for reverting back to App A is added. Strange thing is that launching App B from the home screen does not have any problem. It launches about 1 seconds. It happens only when it is launched by URL scheme.

I tried async call by GCD but it does not help. I think there is something wrong with launching App B rather than something in App A. Because the most time consuming point is in the state of showing splash image. It takes almost 10 seconds.

I am testing in Xcode 8 and iOS 10.

Any advice is welcomed!

**EDIT**

App A ViewController: transit to App B

```
func call() {
    let url = URL(string: "AppB://" + "?type=aa&data=" + testData)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        print("OK")
    }
    else {
        print("NOK")
    }
}
```

App B AppDelegate: return to App A

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let url = URL(string: "AppA://")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
        print("OK")
    }
    else {
        print("NOK")
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does app B do after being launched through URL Scheme? Are you doing something with parameters passed over (if any)?

Comment: I used URL Schema and it won't take much it. Share your demo code, so we can figure out your issue.

Comment: @pnizzle I pass the parameter like this for the test.
AppA://?type=aa&data=aaa.

AppB receives those two parameter.

Comment: What are you passing in testData? Try to remove it and then check it once.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh It still happens even I remove all parameters and use only "AppB://"

Comment: @JohnRoh You are saying you see the splash screen about 10 seconds. Does it takes the same time when you just launching App B?

Comment: @VladislavKovalyov When I open AppB from the home screen, it is OK. It takes less than 1 seconds. But when the AppB is launched by URL scheme from AppA, it takes about 10 seconds in splash image .

Comment: @JohnRoh it is really strange. Usually splash screen takes only the time needed to load all recourses and proceed all operations in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. Do you have any heavyweight code in there? If not, then probably this is iOS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this issue is about calling openURL in AppAloading AppB. But I found out that it is happening during AppB->AppA transition. I could resolve the issue by asynchronous openURL function call in AppB.

Thank you for the comments pnizzle, Nirmalsinh and Vladislav Kovalyov.